# Resize IFrame automatically

Tags: html, css

I have built a chatbot from scratch using React, which works perfectly.

- when I embedded the chatbot to a website using Iframe, It doesn't get his exact `height` and `width`.
- It just takes up the initial `height` of the chatbot which is the icon button to open the chatbot.
- If I give `100%` width and height to the iframe, it takes up the entire screen and because of that the background website is not clickable.

Is there any css hack to this?

Any help is appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, because you cant control the parent dom from the iframe.
so you need a way to set the iframe width/height from the parent page not the iframe.

A js library that's embedded in the parent page is your best bet.

Comment: I see, Is this how all the chatbot companies are doing too? Because this way I'll have to take the button out from the chatbot and create it on the parent page

Comment: Most of them. check for example Intercom's instructions, the ask you to include their js library on your page. After that they essentially have full control over your page.(with great power comes great responsibility)